# Comparison between shutting down an executor service (while awaiting termination) and wait cancellation of submitted tasks (using submit's futures)

Tags: java, spring, executorservice

So the proposed best practice by [Oracle itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for shutting down an `ExecutorService` would be the following:

```
@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp(){
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            if (executorService.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
}
```

This will also take care of cancelling any pending tasks as well. I am wondering *when* the above code snippet is preferred to the following:

```
private List<Future> tasks = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

public void doStuff(){
    for (Service service : services) {
            Future<?> future = executorService.submit(()->service.update(args));
            tasks.add(task);
    }
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp() {

    for (Future task : tasks) {
        task.cancel(false);
    }
}
```

The latter will allow the running tasks to complete without interrupting them (`tasks.cancel(false)`). In this approach there is no timeout so an infinite loop in a task would prevent the application from stopping. Furthermore, we're left with a still running executors service: But should we really care about this if there's the certainty that no other tasks can be submitted after cancelled ones are completed?

I am mostly interested in what is considered a best practice in a situation where one wants to wait termination/completion of a job's tasks before proceeding to the actual shutdown. Why do we actually care about the shutdown of the executor service itself?

Imho, having a list of futures which one would cancel on application shutdown is a much cleaner solution since one might select which are to be interrupted and which to wait for completion.

Any more elaborate insights on this are more than welcome.

These are all part of a Spring bean as you might infer from the `@PotsDestroy` annotation used to designate the `cleanUp` method as a shutdown hook for cleaning up the tasks of the executors service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proposed solution, wait should be called after shutdownNow() method invocation.

> An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of
>   its resources.

**shutdownNow():-**

- Transition the run state to Stop
- Interrupt the worker if started
- Drain the queue - Remove all the threads

**Future.cancel (false):-**

- Doesn't interrupt the running tasks
- The cancel attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has
  already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other
  reason. You may need to have additional logic to handle different
  scenarios. The shutdownNow() already handles those scenarios.

**Short description and recommendation:-**

- Actually, having a `List` object itself is not thread-safe
- Singleton beans are stateless. It should not be maintaining the state
  in the class level. Even if you declare this as prototype bean, it is
  not a good practice to maintain the List (List is not thread safe) of
  futures.

Internally, the executer service implementation classes such as ThreadPoolExecutor, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor etc. takes care of all the thread safety issues. It uses `BlockingQueue` to overcome the thread safety issues. Also, it handles exception and different states accordingly. You may need to understand all the internals (i.e. what is happening under the hood) to come up with a good custom solution.

The easy and best way is to use the **standard implementations (ThreadPoolExecutor, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor etc)** available in the executor service implementations to avoid any adverse effect (i.e. memory leakage, thread safety issues).

Comment: Thanks for the response @notionquest. I suppose `Future.call(false)` is a typo and should have been `Future.cancel(false)`. Other than that I can see your point. Mainly on the beans' statelessness. Wondering about the mutability of the `Future`s and correct me if I am wrong but are you suggesting that the underlying implementation of the `ExecutorService` mutates the `Future`s state during the lifecycle of a thread?